# PostgreSQL automatic timezone conversion to local

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone

I'm struggling with a query that can dynamically convert the `timezone` based on input parameters in `Where` clause. It should be able to determine the appropriate timezone conversion based on the key and values in the `WITH`. The system timezone is in *UTC*.

I have about 8 timezones to work with and looking for a smarter way to detect the conversion without always having to change `At Time Zone 'pst'`

This is what i so far but the syntax needs some help:

```
with
    data(id, timezone) AS (values
      (2, 'US/Pacific'),
      (5, 'US/Mountain'),
      (10, 'US/Eastern'))

select data.id, marg.timestamp, marg.value, structure.market 
from data, marg, structure 
where id in (2,5,10)
and marg.timestamp between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-31'
```

Also, if there is a better way to achieve this I am receptive to feedback.

ideally, the output would look like this:

```
utc                 |id| timezone   | local_time            | value
--------------------+--+------------+---------------------- +----------------
2017-01-01 22:19:36 |2 | US/Pacific | 2017-01-01 15:19:36   | 2435
2017-01-10 22:29:36 |2 | US/Pacific | 2017-01-10 15:29:36   | 215
2017-01-30 22:39:36 |2 | US/Pacific | 2017-01-30 15:29:36   | 2150
2017-01-28 22:19:36 |5 | US/Mountain| 2017-01-28 16:19:36   | 11341
2017-01-29 22:19:36 |5 | US/Mountain| 2017-01-29 16:19:36   | 131
2017-01-04 22:19:36 |10| US/Mountain| 2017-01-04 16:19:36   | 134
2017-01-05 22:19:36 |10| US/Eastern | 2017-01-05 18:19:36   | 2451
```

it takes the system time in UTC and converts to the appropriate timezone local_time

Answer (score 0):

Not sure If I understand you correctly, do you wan to use timezone in some list to convert to? then, like here:

```
t=# with
    data(id, timezone) AS (values
      (2, 'US/Pacific'),
      (5, 'US/Mountain'),
      (10, 'US/Eastern'))
select *, now at time zone timezone ajusted from now()
join data on true;
              now              | id |  timezone   |          ajusted
-------------------------------+----+-------------+----------------------------
 2017-09-28 22:13:27.904796+01 |  2 | US/Pacific  | 2017-09-28 14:13:27.904796
 2017-09-28 22:13:27.904796+01 |  5 | US/Mountain | 2017-09-28 15:13:27.904796
 2017-09-28 22:13:27.904796+01 | 10 | US/Eastern  | 2017-09-28 17:13:27.904796
(3 rows)
```

Comment: something like that. but it needs to pull in other columns needed (`marg.value, structure.market`). i've updated the description with what the output should look like. Thanks for your assistance on this @vao-tsun